# What does $dg|_c(x)$ mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I saw the notation in the context of the definition of a function,

$$f(c, x)=dg|_c(x)$$

where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$. I am having trouble understanding what is going on here. What does the bar mean in this case? How do we evaluate $dg$ at $c$?

Comment: Can you include a link/picture to where you saw this?  I haven't seen this notation before.

Comment: @Mark It is during lecture but I am quite sure I did not record it wrong as I made a double take right then.

Comment: Including the relevant section around your notes might help context wise.

Comment: @mark It's an exercise. We defined $f$ as this and was saying $f$ is smooth if $g$ is.